# Desire2Learn issue with calling API's

Tags: desire2learn

Am trying to use the valance api to call few methods. Am authenticating using https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com from where am getting UserId & UserKey. Now am confused what should i pass in the x_a - x_d parameters for getting the organization info.

What ever i pass i get a 403 forbidden & incorrect token exception.

Some body please help. Am passing folling in the parameters.

x_a : Application ID

x_b : User ID( I got this from https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com)

`x_c : private String calculateParameterExpectation( String key, String httpMethod, String apiPath, long timestamp)
 {
  String unsignedResult = String.format("%s&%s&%s", httpMethod, apiPath, timestamp);
        System.out.println(unsignedResult);
        String signedResult = D2LSigner.getBase64HashString(key, unsignedResult);
        return signedResult;
    } Where key is the App Key`

`x_d : private String calculateParameterExpectation(
            String key, String httpMethod, String apiPath, long timestamp) {
        String unsignedResult = String.format("%s&%s&%s", httpMethod, apiPath, timestamp);
        System.out.println(unsignedResult);
        String signedResult = D2LSigner.getBase64HashString(key, unsignedResult);
        return signedResult;
    } Where key is the User Signature that i got from  https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com`

Am not sure what is done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that *each* back-end service generates a unique UserID/Key pair to go with *each* user and *each* application ID, [upon request by a call from that application ID](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/apiprop.html#get--d2l-auth-api-token).

This explicitly means that User ID/Key pairs are not transferrable from one application to another. Nor are they transferrable from one back-end service to another -- every API-using application should request its own UserID/Key pair for making calls on behalf of each distinct user. Even if you used *your* App ID/Key when using the api-test tool, unless you pointed the tool at the same back-end service you're actually making the API calls against, you won't get back a UserID/Key pair you can use for later making the API calls (against another service).

Please also note that the signing mechanism requires that you use the *upper-case* version of the http-method string (thus `GET`, not `get`), and it requires that you use the *lower-case* version of the api path string (thus `/d2l/auth/api/token`, not `/D2L/AUTH/API/TOKEN`). If you're pointing the api-test tool at the same LMS you're wanting to make API calls against, and you're using the same App ID/Key pair with the api-test tool as you're using in your production code, then I would seek to make sure that you're formatting your base string exactly right for signing.

I would also encourage you to make fuller use D2L's own client SDK libraries for doing the app/user context management and signing, rather than just using the raw signing call from within the library.